# Are there conservative fields which aren't gradient fields?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Is path independence equivalent to being a gradient of a scalar field. I know that all gradient fields are conservative, but are all conservative fields gradient fields?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See [converse of the gradient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem#Converse_of_the_gradient_theorem).

Comment: If $f(x)$ is conservative, then just define $g(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(y)\cdot dy$... which is well-defined by path independence.  Then $\nabla g(x)= f(x)$, showing that $f(x)$ is a gradient field.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Why are you answering in a comment?